# Using Linq to update a List<T> of objects to DB

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, updatemodel

I have a form that returns me a List of FlatSessie objects

in my edit view I edit a few FlatSessie's and get them returned to my Post method in that List object.

In my DB I have Sessies, which I map using Automapper to FlatSessie's and back

now I can not get linq to make the update to the DB for me.

the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Sessies(int id, int? modID, int? projID, string schooljaarparam, List<FlatSessie> sl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            foreach (FlatSessie s in sl) { //i run over all FlatSessies which i get
                Models.Sessies ses = Mapper.Map<FlatSessie, Sessies>(s); // i map them to the Sessies object
                List<Sessies> origReeks = _db.Sessies.Where(p => p.Ses_ID == ses.Ses_ID).ToList(); //i get the original Session by ID. if there is a Session with that ID, if not (the ID will be 0) i do an Insert. if there is i want to do an Update.

                if (origReeks.Count > 0) {
                    //it's an update
                    UpdateModel(origReeks.First(); //doesnt work
                    //_db.Sessies.Attach(ses, origReeks.First()); //doesnt work, gives me an error on used ID...
                    _db.SubmitChanges();
                } else {
                    //no sessies yet, add them, this works.
                    _db.Sessies.InsertOnSubmit(ses);
                    _db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            TempData["okmsg"] = "De sessies zijn opgeslagen";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //if not valid, i return the viewdata which i need.

        Module m = _db.Modules.First(md => md.Mod_ID == modID.Value);
        int antses = m.Mod_AantalSessies.Value;

        List<List<SelectListItem>> lpllst = new List<List<SelectListItem>>(antses);


        for (int i = 0; i < antses; i++) {
            lpllst.Add(MvcApplication.lesplaatsList(schooljaarparam, -1));
        }

        ViewData["lesplist"] = lpllst;
        ViewData["lglist"] = MvcApplication.lesgeverList();

        return View(sl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work to provide a [prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470808.aspx) to UpdateModel (`FlatSessie[n]`, where n is such that it matches the actual input name of the model element in question) so that it knows which properties to map onto the object, but because you are getting a list of these it might not.  Have you tried updating the retrieved model using the data from the matching `FlatSessie` object directly?

Also, once you get this to work, you might want to do a single SubmitChanges for all inserts/updates (outside the loop) so that you get the entire submit wrapped in a single transaction.  This will make it easier if there are errors to correct them and resubmit -- since you won't have some changes already committed causing further potential errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try to get it to work. i also have another problem with the same code, but in its view. you might want to check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454319/model-binding-form-to-a-list-using-dropdown-binding-failing-1-way-for-dropdown it might more clear how to fix this issue too that way :)

Comment: AWESOME. it works!

my updatemodel just had to be changed to: 

UpdateModel(origReeks.First(), "[" + counter + "]");
with counter being an int incremented after every loop.
because that's how the formcollection comes in. THANKS!!