# ASP.NET MVC bug binding collection of DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections

I have a view with 1 dropdown generated from Model property and 3 additional dropdowns that are generated from array property

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentType, Model.AgentTypeListItems)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AgentTypes.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentTypes[i], Model.AgentTypeListItems)
}
```

The controller method initializes AgentTypeListItems collection + sets default values for AgentType dropdown and 3 dropdowns for the collection:

```
var model = new OptionsViewModel();

// for DropDownListFor
model.AgentTypeListItems = new[]
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" },
};

// 1 dropdown in the model
model.AgentType = "2";

// 3 dropdowns in array
model.AgentTypes = new[] { "3", "2", "1" };

return View(model);
```

When I open it in browser I get "2" everywhere though AgentTypes array was initialized with different values(!):

[image: this is wrong]

When I replace DropDownListFor with TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AgentTypes[i])
```

I get the correct values in the inputs (!):

[image: this is how it should be]

It means the TextBoxFor works as expected, but DropDownListFor doesn't.

Is it a bug in MVC DropDownListFor?

**UPDATE**
Here is the model class:

```
public class OptionsViewModel
{
    public SelectListItem[] AgentTypeListItems { get; set; }
    public string AgentType { get; set; }
    public string[] AgentTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your HTML that is rendered.  Do all the dropdowns have the same ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know that this post is more than a year old but it seems still to be a bug. Replacing

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentType, Model.AgentTypeListItems)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AgentTypes.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentTypes[i], Model.AgentTypeListItems)
}
```

with

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentType, Model.AgentTypeListItems)
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AgentTypes.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentTypes[i], new SelectList(Model.AgentTypeListItems, "Value", "Text", Model.AgentTypes[i])
}
```

works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug still exists in MVC 4.5. Using the suggested fix solved the problem when working with array/collections and DropDownListsFor

Answer (score 2):

comment out your first line,
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AgentType, Model.AgentTypeListItems) 
what happens then?

Try this:

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AgentTypes.Length;  i++)
        {     
            string selected = Model.AgentTypes[i];
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => selected, new SelectList(Model.AgentTypeListItems, "Text", "Value",Model.AgentTypes[i]))
        }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but this may be an issue with the binding noted here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501498/dropdownlistfor-not-binding-on-edit-view-with-repeating-items-listt

Comment: Commenting first line just makes all 3 other dropdowns have default value, but not 3,2,1 as expected. Will give a try for your second snippet, thanks.

Comment: interesting.. when I commented out the first the others worked. The snippet above worked for me as well.

Comment: Just created a new blank MVC3 project and still get 1,1,1 instead of 3,2,1 when commenting out the first dropdown. Btw, I've added the model class to the question.

Comment: did you try the block of code I have above? it works for me with 3,2,1 (I had 1,1,1 before it)

Comment: I tried, but in your case it renders "selected" (may be wrong here) as name for all 3 dropdowns, which means I'll be unable to save the values. Anyway, if it even works, it looks like an ugly workaround. I how to get it work as I originally wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is similar to situations in WPF and Windows Forms where using the same source item for the list choices "links" all the UI elements together behind the scenes? I recall having to create separate copies of the list object in those situations. Might be worth a try here.