# Binding dropdowns to a collection in asp MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to be able to build a dynamic list of dropdowns in an ASP MVC 3 project.  My model contains the following:

```
    public IList<Collections.Division> Divisions { get; set; }


    public SelectList DivisionSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            DivisionRepository repo = new DivisionRepository();

            var divisions = repo.Divisions;

            return new SelectList(divisions,"DivisionId","DivisionName");
        }
    }
```

And the Division class looks like this:

```
    public class Division
    {
      public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    }
```

I build a list of dropdowns in the view like this:

```
     @for(int i = 0;i< Model.Divisions.Count;i++)
    {
            @Model.Divisions[i].DivisionId //for debug only
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Divisions[i].DivisionId,Model.DivisionSelectList)
            <br/>
    }
```

The list of divisions is populated before rendering the view and I can see the data looks correct but the dropdowns items are not being selected.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in MVC, see here: 
[DropDownListFor not binding on Edit View with repeating items (List<T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501498/dropdownlistfor-not-binding-on-edit-view-with-repeating-items-listt)

I had to do this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Divisions[i].DivisionId,new SelectList(Model.DivisionSelectList,"Value","Text",Model.Divisions[i].DivisionId))
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a list of selected item type in your controller action from

```
 DivisionRepository repo = new DivisionRepository(); 
 foreach(var item in repo.Divisions)
 {
      Divisions.add(item );
 }
    var divisions = repo.Divisions;
```

Comment: The list of divisions is populated when the model is created like this: private void GetDivisions(int taskId)
        {
            DivisionTaskRepository repo = new DivisionTaskRepository();

            Divisions =
                repo.GetByTaskId(taskId).Where(x => x.LeadDivision != true).Select(
                    x => new Collections.Division {DivisionId = x.DivisionId}).ToList();

        }

Comment: Note that the division repository is populated from a database and contains all the Division Entities.  This is not the same as the local Divisions list which just contains a list of division Ids we are interested in.  The code in this answer would not work.  Note also I do get the data I expect, the problem is that the dropdowns don't bind.