# Unable to bind Model Property to SelectListItem

Tags: c#, razor

I have a couple of classes like below -

```
public class P
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PDetail> PDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my View, I am displaying it as -

```
@foreach (var detail in Model.PDetails)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => detail.Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => detail.Price, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Price" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here, I am able to display `detail.Price` for each detail object, but `detail.Type` is not getting selected from `ViewData["Types"]` dropdownlist.

PS: `ViewData["Types"]` is just a dictionary of typeIds = {1,2,3...}

### Edit1

As suggested below, I changed the View to (modified a bit as `PDetails` is `ICollection`) -

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PDetails.ElementAt(i).Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But it is still not working. Is the fact that `PDetails` is `ICollection` and binding list is `IEnumerable` might be causing this issue here?

Comment: Any help here? I am still facing problem with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the solution throught another post, so putting it here. This is due to a bug in MVC4 with DropDownListFor binding detailed here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501498](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501498/dropdownlistfor-not-binding-on-edit-view-with-repeating-items-listt/3529347#3529347)

I changed the View to look like below and it worked fine.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PDetails.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PDetails.ElementAt(i).Type, new SelectList(ViewData["Types"] as IEnumerable, "Value", "Text", Model.PDetails.ElementAt(i).Type), "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should you the variable which is declared in lambda expression `m =>`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PDetails.Length; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PDetails[i].Type, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Types"], "--Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference? You are also doing the same expect using for instead of foreach

Comment: I'm using the provided `m` variable in lambda instead of custom `detail` variable

Comment: Oops!! Missed that :)

Comment: Did this. Please see Edit1 above.